# For arbitrary subspaces U,V and W of a finite dimensional vectorspace , which of the following relations hold

Tags: linear-algebra

For arbitrary subspaces  $U$, $V$ and $W$ of a finite dimensional vector space, which of the following hold

a) $U\cap(V+ W) \subset  U\cap V + U\cap W $

b) $U\cap(V+ W) \supset  U\cap V + U\cap W $

c) $(U\cap V)+ W \subset  (U +W) \cap (V+W) $

d) $(U\cap V)+ W \supset   (U +W) \cap (V+W) $

> I don't know to solve this. This is a CSIR NET QUESTION and they have given answer as options b) and c). Please help...

Comment: the first one has a counter example: U is the x-axis, V is the y axis and W is the line y=x all in the xy-plane. The third is trivially true.

Comment: I see you are fairly new to Math.StackExchange. Please use dollar signs around _entire formulas_, not each time around individual math symbols; the spacing will look a lot better.

Answer (score 2):

Hint- use the fact that if $W_{1}$ and $W_{2}$ are two subspace of a vector space $V$ then $W_{1}\cap W_{2}$ is the largest subspace of $V$ contained in $W_{1}$ and $W_{2}$ and $W_{1}+W_{2}$ is the smallest subspace containing both $W_{1}$ and $W_{2}$.